# How to convert Rc<str> to String in Rust

Tags: rust

I am currently trying to build an interpreter in Rust in order to better understand it(both interpreters and Rust).
I converted input string into `Rc<str>` and in later stage of compilation I want to create a `String` from part of it. I couldn't find anything that can help me in documentation so I wrote a simple function that looks like this`

```
fn string_from_rc(r: &std::rc::Rc<str>) -> String {
    let chars = r.chars();
    let mut s = String::new();
    for c in chars {
        s.push(c);
    }
    s
}
```

but I am sure there is a better way to go about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.to_string()` is enough:

```rust
fn string_from_rc(r: &std::rc::Rc<str>) -> String {
    r.to_string()
}
```

Equivalent would also be a `.to_owned()` called on the `str` value. One simple thing to remember is that if you have a `&Rc<str>`, then *all* the methods of `&str` are still available, but maybe in some cases the trait methods of the smart pointer type (here `Rc`) get in the way.

`.to_string()` comes from the `ToString` trait, which `str` of course implements.

Comment: Note that while `&str` has a specialized `ToString` implementation, `Rc<str>` does not, so using `to_string()` goes through the `Display` default implementation, more or less as if you had written `format!("{}", r)`. I would use `to_owned` in a case like this; it is faster and, probably, more semantically accurate, if a few extra characters (`(**r).to_owned()`).